# TypeScript doesn't love nesting?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript

VS 2017 show warning:

> TS:Cannot find module

but path is valid:

[image]

and show warnings about decorators:

> Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to
>   change in a future release

but tsconfig.json have  "experimentalDecorators": true

However, the project runs successfully.

Maybe nesting creates a problem?

[image]

Components above level have no problem.

I noticed that such warnings appeared where js files are located.

[image]

What i doing wrong? How fix this problem?

P.S Sorry for bad English `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 1):

> but path is valid:

Your screenshot shows `@angular/core/core.d.ts`. `@angular/core` will resolve to `@angular/core/index.d.ts`. I don't see it in the screenshot.

[image]

If you do have `index.d.ts`, just restart your IDE. When you do a fresh npm install, the file system changes aggressively and the OS fails to notify listeners.

> but tsconfig.json have "experimentalDecorators": true

Again, restart your IDE. If you change tsconfig.json when a file is open, it might not get re-error-checked

Comment: I dont have @angular/core/index.d.ts... 
What should I do to fix it? 
Why other files do not have such errors?

Comment: After a restart, there are no errors, but decorator warning have alive...

Comment: Eh, now again error Cannot find module, but i don't use npm install... =( Some ideas?